# Evaluation of polynomial when using elliptic curves for verifiable secret sharing

Tags: elliptic-curves, secret-sharing

I am implementing the following the algorithm instructions as shown in [1](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.67.9913&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (section IV, B).

When trying to verify the share given the commits, $a_jG$ verifier $i$ checks whether $f(i)G=\sum_{j=0}^{t} (x_i)^ja_jG$.

The phrasing of the verification is unclear to me, on the left side of the equation there is a scalar on the elliptic curve, on the right side there is a a polynomial.

Should the polynomial on the right be evaluated at point $i$?

[A robust threshold elliptic curve digital signature providing a new verifiable secret sharing scheme](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.67.9913&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: linked question : https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12407/elliptic-curve-verifiable-secret-sharing

Answer (score 1):

I cannot access the linked document, but I think that $G$ is a generator point of the elliptic curve, so you will have points on both sides.